# MVC cookie path not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie path like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(
             new HttpCookie("test", "hello") { Path = @"/admin", 
             Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)});

        return RedirectToAction("About", "Admin");
    }
}

public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        var cookieCount = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Count;
        return View();
    }
}
```

When the Index action redirects to the Admin/About action, the cookie is not retreived and cookieCount is zero.

If I change my cokie path to "/" it works fine with cookieCount being set to one.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's case sensitive. So try: `Path = @"/Admin"` if you redirect to `/Admin/About`. Or use lowercase urls.

Comment: Holy cow, you are so right. I changed the cookie path to Admin and it worked. Very lame.